# Multiple Group by in sql without duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table name 'Items' with content

```
   id    title          cat          subcat      subcat2
   1     Notebook 219   Computers    Notebooks   Ultrabooks
   2     Notebook 200   Computers    Notebooks   Notebooks
   3     Notebook 300   Computers    Chromebook  Notebooks
   4     Notebook 233   Computers    Notebooks
```

I am using this query

```
select cat,subcat,subcat2 
  from items where cat='Computers' 
 group by subcat,subcat2 
 order by subcat asc
```

this query returns  Notebooks, Chromebooks, Ultrabooks, Notebooks.

I want subcat and subcat2 should print only once. Also the empty space should be removed

Is it possible we can avoid duplicate rows?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you're asking, what would your expected result be?

Comment: The result should not have duplicate subcats. If you look Subcat has notebooks and subt2 has also notebooks. So when we would print the result would be having two times "notebooks"

Comment: What do you mean by *...the empty space should be grouped*? Can you post the exact desired output in a tabular form?

Comment: @peterm sorry I mean the empty should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

[Referenced SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93ec3/3/0)

```
SELECT distinct t1.cat, t1.subcat, t1.subcat2
  FROM items as t1
  WHERE t1.cat='computers' GROUP BY t1.subcat
```

output as

```
|       CAT |     SUBCAT |    SUBCAT2 |
|-----------|------------|------------|
| Computers | Chromebook |  Notebooks |
| Computers |  Notebooks | Ultrabooks |
```

Comment: i want to print all subcats but each should not be repeated.

Comment: @user2535089 updated answer, is this what you want? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93ec3/3/0

Comment: I want to display only sub_cat and sub_cat2 but they should not have duplicate values. For example Notebooks in sub_cat should not be displayed in sub_cat2

Comment: please post your expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT subcat
  FROM items 
 WHERE cat = 'computers' 
   AND COALESCE(subcat, '') <> ''
UNION
SELECT subcat2
  FROM items 
 WHERE cat = 'computers' 
   AND COALESCE(subcat2, '') <> ''
ORDER BY subcat
```

Output:

```
|     SUBCAT |
|------------|
| Chromebook |
|  Notebooks |
| Ultrabooks |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcb79/1)** demo

Comment: @user2535089 Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you talk about `Notebooks->Notebooks` so you can use the following:

```
select cat,subcat,
       CASE WHEN subcat2=subcat THEN '' ELSE subcat2 END 
       as subcat2
  from items where cat='Computers' 
 group by subcat,
          CASE WHEN subcat2=subcat THEN '' ELSE subcat2 END 
 order by subcat asc
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4891a/3)

Comment: I don't want duplicate subcats. I want only to print subcat and subcat2 but it should unique. For example Notebooks should come only once.